# Read an holding register bit by bit Siemens

Tags: python, modbus-tcp, pymodbus

I need to read a Siemens 1200 holding register bit by bit with python, searching on the web I found PyModbus an excellent library, but with it I'm only able to read the holding register such an integer and not bit by bit.

This is the code:

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient

client = ModbusTcpClient('x.y.z.w', port=xxx)


result = client.write_registers(1, [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512]) # write some register

results = client.read_holding_registers(0, 50) # read the first fifty register like int
print("0-50", results.registers)
results = client.read_holding_registers(50, 50) # read the last fifty register like int
print("50-100:", results.registers)


client.close()
```

Someone have any hint?

Comment: A Modbus holding register *is* a 16-bit integer, the protocol has no provision for reading the bits individually.  You can of course do whatever you want with the bits of the integer once you've received it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient
from pymodbus.payload import BinaryPayloadDecoder
from pymodbus.constants import Endian

CLP_MB = ModbusTcpClient(['IP'], port=502)

adress_Tag=1
adress_Tag=int(adress_Tag)
size=50
value = CLP.read_coils(adress_Tag, size, unit=0)
#last part
value_bit_0 = int(value.bits[0])
value_bit_1 = int(value.bits[1])
..... 
you can use a for loop to automation this last part
```